# Identifer versus keyword

Tags: java, assertions, scjp

I read in the book for OCJP for Java6 the part with assertions. I reached the part where it gives me an overview of how the compiler reacts if the word 'assert' is used as keyword or as an identifier.

What is the difference between a `Keyword` and an `identifier`? Can anyone give me a simple explanation and additionally one or more examples for both?

Comment: Thanks for all answers. They did help me a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The terms "keyword" and "identifier" are not Java specific.

A keyword is a reserved word from the [Java keyword list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) provide the compiler with instructions. As keywords are reserved, they cannot be used by the programmer for variable or method names.

Examples:

```
final
class
this
synchronized
```

Identifiers are the names of variables, methods, classes, packages and interfaces. They must be composed of letters, numbers, the underscore _ and the dollar sign $. Identifiers may only begin with a letter, the underscore or a dollar sign.

Examples:

```
int index;
String name;
```

`index` and `name` are valid identifiers here. `int` is a keyword.

A keyword cannot be used as an identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Identifiers are names of variables. For example in

```
int a = 3;
```

`a` would the identifier. Keywords, on the other hand, are reserved (i.e. you can't name a variable with a keyword), pre-defined words that have a specific meaning in the language. For example in

```
if (a == 3)
    System.out.println("Hello World");
```

`if` is a keyword. It has a specific function and cannot be used as a variable name. Moreover, the words used to declare primitive types are all keywords as well, e.g. `int`, `char`, `long`, `boolean` etc. You can see a full list of Java keywords [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords)

Answer (score 2):

Keywords are reserved words like `new,static,public,if,else,..`

An identifier can be a name of any variable.

```
int age = 26;
```

`"age"` here is an identifier, while `int` is a reserved word.

The following example won't compile:

```
String static = "hello";
int public = 4;
```

you can't do this because `"static"` and `"public"` are `keywords`, that in this case are being used as `identifiers`, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume an identifier is your own (function name, var name, ...); and a keyword is 'class' or 'assert' or 'while' -- language defined identifiers, in other words

Answer (score 0):

The following page contains a list of Java identifiers and keywords related to 1Z0-803 OCA Certification.
[Java Identifiers Keywords](http://www.j2eeonline.com/java2-programmers-certification/module2/identifiers-keywords.jsp)

Comment: Link-only answers are not popular on this site.  You should answer the question in the body of your answer, summarizing from a Website if necessary.