# java annotation with argument named default

Tags: java, java-annotations

Is it possible to create an annotation that uses the keyword *default* as one of the parameters?

Something like

```
// Annotation Definition

public @interface Optional {
    Object default() default null;
}
```

-

```
// Usage - function declaration

public void callableMethod(@OptionalParam(default = "foo") String username) {}
```

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, no because "default" is a reserved keyword. You would have to call it something different like "defaultVal".

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547009/identifer-versus-keyword